# How to lowercase selected item in a list

Tags: python, string, lowercase

I have

```
x= ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
```

and I want to lower case only `'BB'`.

Answer (score 0):

To transform a string to lowercase, you use

```
string.lower()
```

To answer your question, use

```
x[1] = x[1].lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try

`
x = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']

Str = x[1]

print(Str.lower())

`

#0 = AA, 1 = BB, 2 = CC

use 0 1 or 2 with x[NUMBER]

I hope this works for you!!

EDIT: or you can use x[num] directly instead of putting it in a variable